# Sales of books of Rousseau in Versailles

Tags: france, french-revolution, literature

I am currently comparing the sales of books by Rousseau and Voltaire in the city of Versailles, and I noticed a very important peak in sales of books by Rousseau in 1781. I was wondering if anyone knows if there is any particular relation between Rousseau and Versailles, or something that might explain this peak. Same question for Voltaire and Geneva.

Comment: Would you mind sharing these sales numbers, so we have an idea of what you're talking about?

Comment: @Semaphore Well the sales in Versailles represent 36% out of all sold books i.e. 1400 out of 3,858 total

Comment: Probably it was just a royal fad.

Comment: @TylerDurden But still, that seems to me to important to just be a "royal fad"

Comment: Ok so here's what I found. There is a librarian by the name of Poinçot who acquired 1300 copies of Les Confessions of Rousseau. But I can seem to be able to find who is he and to whom did he sell these books.

Comment: Wasn't Poinçot the publisher?

Comment: What is the source for all these data?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Have you heard of the STN ?http://fbtee.uws.edu.au/stn/interface/